# Redirect to another page : NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have tried almost all the solution provided here, but as I am new to nodejs I am missing some part in my code. Please help me finding it.
On clicking login button i want to redirect my page to another simple page.

Here is my **login_authentication.js**

```
window.onload = function() {


    var username    = document.getElementById("username");
    var password    = document.getElementById("password");
    var loginButton = document.getElementById("login");


    loginButton.onclick = function (req,res) {
        if ( username.value == "" || password.value == ""){
            alert("Please fill out details!");
        }else {
            //alert(username.value);
            username.value = "";
            password.value = "";

        router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
            // res.send('respond with a resource');
            res.render('homepage', { title: 'Thank You' });
        });
        }

    }

}
```

Here is **app.js**

```
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users); // need to show this page rest is default code
```

Here is **users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 // res.send('respond with a resource');
  res.render('homepage', { title: 'Sample' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I want to redirect my page when user clicks on login button whose code is in login_authentication. Thanks for any help.

Comment: use window.location="/users" instead of router.get('/users') in login_authentication.js

Comment: @farhadamjady thank you sooo much. It is doing what i want to achieve. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `window.location="/users"` instead of `router.get('/users')` in `login_authentication.js`

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have some form, which has some input fields.

```
<form method="post" action="/thank-you" id="login">
<!-- Some input fields -->
<button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In your frontend js, you will handle the click event. If your validation passes, then you will submit the form to nodejs

```
var username    = document.getElementById("username");
var password    = document.getElementById("password");
var loginButton = document.getElementById("login");


loginButton.onclick = function (req,res) {
    if ( username.value == "" || password.value == ""){
        alert("Please fill out details!");
    }else {
        document.getElementById("login").submit();
    }

}
```

Here in node at this route you will receive the request, make sure it has the `thank-you.html` file.

```
//NODE
router.post('/thank-you', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('thank-you.html');
});
```

Comment: tried it. but did not work. I am writing this code my login_authentication.js in if condition.

Comment: I dont see you are submitting your form

Comment: can you tell me exactly where i should be doing that ? see my edits in login_authentication.js